# Share current user information in Angular controllers

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular 1.5 and I call a web api (/api/users/self) to get information about the current authenticated user (name, id, ...) so I can use that information on my Angular controllers.

```
(function () {

  "use strict";

  angular.module("app").controller("MessageInboxController", MessageInboxController);

  MessageInboxController.$inject = ["$timeout", "messageService", "userService"];

  function MessageInboxController($timeout, messageService, userService) {

    var vm = this;

  }

})();
```

On message controller I will call the UserService to get current user info.

So in many controllers I need to do this ...

Is there a way to call the UserAPI once and share this info with all controllers?

What is your advice?

Comment: Store the user info in a variable on your service or a value

Answer (score 2):

Create a *service* to store your data in and **inject** it into your *controllers*:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('DataRepo', function() {
  var data = {
      name: 'Superhero'
    };
    
    return {
      data: data
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl1', function($scope, DataRepo) {
    $scope.name = DataRepo.data.name;
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl2', function($scope, DataRepo) {
  $scope.DataRepo = DataRepo;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
    Hello, {{name}}!
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">
    Hello, {{DataRepo.data.name}}!
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use an authentication service and keeping the user object in cache.

If you are sending the user object alongwith the Main page when it gets rendered from the web-app:

```
// Authentication service for user variables
angular.module('users').factory('Authentication', ['$window',
    function($window) {
        var auth = {
            // if you are sending the user object when rendering the page
            user: $window.user
        };
        return auth;
    }
]);
```

You can inject this service in all your controllers and get to the user through Authentication.user.

Or you can use a call to the web service from your angular service.

In your service if the user object is null call to the web-service if its not null return the user.